# change default apache port

Tags: apache, url

I have question about apache, as I know, by default apache work on port 80, I need to change this default port to another, say 8080.

actually, I have changed this port successfully, by editing on apache configuration on the 
`Listen 80` to `Listen 8080`

but the problem is, I need to add :8080 inside url, so I request site with like this:
http://localhost:8080

Is it possible to remove 8080 on the url?

because I need to off port 80, without getting down the server for public access.

Comment: Hi, your question isn't really on-topic for stackoverflow in my view. I'm Voting off-topic since the question is about network/server issues and unfortunately won't get any better answers from moving to serverfault. (hoxworth is spot with the answer)

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to connect a standard browser to a non-standard HTTP port without explicitly declaring the port as part of the URL, no.

Comment: Hi hoxworth, thanks for the answer, how I can do this? maybe you can give me anotes :)

Comment: By "explicitly declaring as part of the URL" I think hoxworth meant exactly what you wrote in the question, i.e. `http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

try...

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

You have multiple domains going to the same IP and also want to serve multiple ports. By defining the ports in the "NameVirtualHost" tag, you can allow this to work. If you try using  without the NameVirtualHost name:port or you try to use the Listen directive, your configuration will not work.

```
Server configuration

Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
ServerName www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-8080
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName www.example2.org
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
ServerName www.example2.org
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-8080
</VirtualHost>
```